# Remove a permission from my Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app that requires user_friends permission, but I don't actually need this permission anymore. How can I remove it (otherwise I will have to submit the app for review by August 1)

Comment: just don´t ask for the permission anymore...

Comment: Where is that? 
I am only using the API to automate posting on my facebook page.

Comment: _“Where is that?”_ - wherever you implemented the login flow, and specified what permissions to ask for via the scope parameter. If your app is not currently asking for this permission at all, then you can just ignore it.